# Display custom error page in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I can try to make custom error page in angular js
means that when 404 error occurred then display 404.html page
and when 500 error occurred then display 500.html page like so on
so please tell me how can i make this..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this with a request interceptor.  You didn't provide us with what you use for routing so you'll have to insert your code to route to a 404 page and a 500 page.

The factory will look like this:

```
angular.module("app").factory('sessionInterceptor', [factory]);
function factory() {
    var requestInterceptor = {
        response: function(response) {
            // Code you want for successful responses here
            return response;
        },
        responseError: function(rejection) {
            if (rejection.status === 404) {
                // 404 code here
            }
            return rejection;
        }
    };

    return requestInterceptor;
}
```

Then you need to add the interceptor in a config block to the `$httpProvider`:

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('sessionInterceptor');
}])
```

All network requests using `$http` will now pass through the request interceptor.